# Storing a string with many types of characters

Tags: java

how do i store

```
 "CREATE COLUMN VIEW "_USE_BID"."rev26/FREESTYLE" TYPE JOIN WITH PARAMETERS ( joinIndex = "REV26"."SIMPLECOMPANY", joinIndexType = 0, viewAttribute = ('ID', "REV26"."SIMPLECOMPANY", "ID", '', 'default', 'attribute', '', 'rev26/FREESTYLE$ID'), freestyleSearchAttribute = 'ID:0.0', viewAttribute = ('NAME', "REV26"."SIMPLECOMPANY", "NAME", '', 'default', 'attribute', '', 'rev26/FREESTYLE$NAME'), freestyleSearchAttribute = 'NAME:0.0'
"
```

as a single string in java? this is a SQL query which i would like to execute.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Manually escape your "  via \"

- http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/character-escape-codes-in-java.html

> String queryString = ""; put your statement in it and escape your " to
>   \"

Comment: ' is not needed to be prefixed wit \

Comment: sure it is http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/character-escape-codes-in-java.html

Comment: @EvilP - not in a String. You have to escape it when you want to use it as a char literal: `'\''` - but this is ok: `"'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
"CREATE COLUMN VIEW \"_USE_BID\".\"rev26/FREESTYLE\" TYPE JOIN WITH PARAMETERS ( joinIndex = \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", joinIndexType = 0, viewAttribute = ('ID', \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", \"ID\", '', 'default', 'attribute', '', 'rev26/FREESTYLE$ID'), freestyleSearchAttribute = 'ID:0.0', viewAttribute = ('NAME', \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", \"NAME\", '', 'default', 'attribute', '', 'rev26/FREESTYLE$NAME'), freestyleSearchAttribute = 'NAME:0.0'
```

"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should need to do is escape all your double-quotes. In other words, all your " characters should be changed to \" ...

```
String sqlStatement = "CREATE COLUMN VIEW \"_USE_BID\".\"rev26/FREESTYLE\" TYPE JOIN WITH PARAMETERS ( joinIndex = \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", joinIndexType = 0, viewAttribute = ('ID', \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", \"ID\", '', 'default', 'attribute', '', 'rev26/FREESTYLE$ID'), freestyleSearchAttribute = 'ID:0.0', viewAttribute = ('NAME', \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", \"NAME\", '', 'default', 'attribute', '', 'rev26/FREESTYLE$NAME'), freestyleSearchAttribute = 'NAME:0.0'";
```

However, there are several things in your statement that might encourage you to split it up into smaller Strings. For example, the ID and NAME columns are both basically the same statement, so you can simply have a template String and replace the blanks with the column name (either ID of NAME, in this case). For example...

```
String columnTemplate = "viewAttribute = ('<COLUMN>', \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", \"<COLUMN>\", '', 'default', 'attribute', '', 'rev26/FREESTYLE$<COLUMN>'), freestyleSearchAttribute = '<COLUMN>:0.0'";

String idColumn = columnTemplate.replaceAll("<COLUMN>","ID");
String nameColumn = columnTemplate.replaceAll("<COLUMN>","NAME");

String joinIndex = "joinIndex = \"REV26\".\"SIMPLECOMPANY\", joinIndexType = 0, " + idColumn + ", " + nameColumn;

String sqlStatement = "CREATE COLUMN VIEW \"_USE_BID\".\"rev26/FREESTYLE\" TYPE JOIN WITH PARAMETERS ( " + joinIndex + ")";
```

This would help you construct SQL statements quicker/easier by removing repetition, and also helps you to find errors in your statement by making it less complicated overall.